# Casting a column value as VARCHAR2() that holds 9 characters (TOPIC: ORACLE SQL & PL for Developers)

Tags: sql, oracle, varchar2

I've cast a column value as VARCHAR2(9) in my query to make it as a varchar2() that hold 9 characters.

It's been suggested to me that VARCHAR2(10) works better and should be a solution to any requirement that asks for VARCHAR2 capable of holding 9 characters.

Expert advice?

Comment: Read about nls_length_semantics: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50950

Answer (score 3):

- If you need to hold 9 bytes of characters then use `VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)`.
- If you need to hold 9 characters (of any byte width) then use `VARCHAR2(9 CHAR)`.
- If you need to hold 10 bytes of characters then use `VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)`.
- If you need to hold 10 characters (of any byte width) then use `VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)`.

We can't advise you what to use but if you only want 9 characters then use `VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)` or `VARCHAR2(9 CHAR)` (as appropriate for the type of characters you will be storing).

> It's been suggested to me that `VARCHAR2(10)` works better and should be a solution to any requirement that asks for `VARCHAR2` capable of holding 9 characters.

I suggest you get that person to explain why they are suggesting adding another character; because if you only need to store 9 characters then specifying a limit of 10 seems to be wrong.

---

**For example:**

If you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value VARCHAR2(10) );
```

And try to insert 9 unicode characters (at 3-bytes each):

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
  VALUES ( UNISTR( '\2600\2601\2602\2603\2604\2605\2606\2607\2608' ) );
```

An exception is raised:

> ```
> ORA-12899: value too large for column "SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLE_NAME"."VALUE" (actual: 27, maximum: 10)
> ```

However:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value VARCHAR2(9 CHAR) );

INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
  VALUES ( UNISTR( '\2600\2601\2602\2603\2604\2605\2606\2607\2608' ) );
```

Works without error and inserts the 9 unicode characters.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0ca53522710b3b8763e0d7f7baf53663)*

Comment: Official documentation says `VARCHAR2(size [BYTE | CHAR])`, not `character`

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov Updated it to `CHAR` to reflect the documented syntax; however `CHARACTER` works on all the versions I've tested it on.

Comment: That is because bothboth are subtypes with  CHARACTER  defined in sys.standard as subtype of CHAR.   
  "subtype CHAR is VARCHAR2;" and 
  "subtype CHARACTER is CHAR;"